# Matplotlib hangs if AVAssetReader was used

Tags: python, c++, macos, matplotlib, core-audio

I have a library which performs some actions with audio files. For testing purposes I made a python interface (using boost::python) and now try to visualize some data.

When I tried to make some matplotlib plots I faced the following issue: if I read a mediafile with the library and then call `matplotlib.pyplot.show()` matplotlib UI hangs right after it appears: I see the plot but cant close/resize/interact with the window, mouse cursor shows "busy wheel".

I found the line causing this freeze (if I place `return` to the line before `show()` works fine and if `retrun` is on the next line `show()` hangs):

```
mReader  = [[AVAssetReader alloc]initWithAsset:ass error:&mReaderError];
```

So what's happening:

- native function is called
- GIL is released (`PyEval_SaveThread`)
- `[[AVAssetReader alloc]initWithAsset]` is called
- GIL is reacquired (`PyEval_RestoreThread`)
- native function returns
- plt.plot([1])
- plt.show()

And matplotlib hangs. 
I'm pretty sure that the library code itself is fine (it is tested and works well on both osx and ios) but there is some conflict between using CoreAudio and "something in GUI".

Here is a partial backtrace of hanged process:

```
frame #0: 0x00007fff8b778ef8 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 440
frame #1: 0x00007fff8d7287b7 HIToolbox`ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479
frame #2: 0x00007fff8d7285bc HIToolbox`_BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
frame #3: 0x00007fff8e48524e AppKit`_DPSNextEvent + 1434
frame #4: 0x00007fff8e48489b AppKit`-[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
frame #5: 0x00007fff8e47899c AppKit`-[NSApplication run] + 553
frame #6: 0x00000001054b3fea _macosx.so`show + 218
frame #7: 0x00000001000997cc Python`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 17823
frame #8: 0x000000010009d103 Python`fast_function + 203
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is not actually the answer but a workaround. It makes things work but is too ugly to be a final solution.

If UI is used *before* `AVAssetReader` all works fine. I think something is being correctly initialized it this case.

This code hangs:

```
data = native_module.get_data_using_coreaudio()
plt.plot(data)
plt.show()
```

but this does not:

```
plt.plot([0])
plt.show()
plt.cla()
data = native_module.get_data_using_coreaudio()
plt.plot(data)
plt.show()
```